# Pointer to member function with move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, move, members

I've just came upon a strange construct:

> void (std::thread::*&&)()

I know it is a sort of a pointer to a class member function. But how to interpret the '&&' operand? What is the meaning of this?

Comment: This declares an rvalue reference to pointer to non-static member function of `std::thread` class taking no arguments and returning nothing. Note that `&&` in this context is not used as logical and operator.

Comment: Your title/tag indicates you already know it's related to moving, i.e. being an rvalue reference, so why would the meaning of that be any different just because this is a pointer-to-method?

Comment: @underscore_d Agree, I should have given it a little more thought before posting the question. I panicked first, it is not what we used to deal with on everyday basis.